# Remove google's markers from google_maps_flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

Objective:
To be able to show custom markers from dev only and disable google maps' default markers.

Description:
I am trying to put markers in `GoogleMap`  from [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter) plugin but Google already has its own markers so it is getting in the way of the markers that I am trying to add. Is there any way to just show the map and add user-defined markers only? If not is it possible to minimize the number of markers shown by default map?

Answer (score 0):

Just looked around and found some possible fix.
Seems like we can generate map style from this website:
[Styling Wizard](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/).

From there I toned down landmarks and then I was able to remove markers using this:

```dart
 final String mapStyle =
                    await rootBundle.loadString('assets/map/map_style.txt');
  //Set it on mapcontroller after map is created. 

 onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
              if (_controller.isCompleted) {
                return;
              }
              controller.setMapStyle(mapStyle);
              _controller.complete(controller);
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// create a function to create custom marker
Future<BitmapDescriptor> createCustomMarkerBitmap() async {
  Uint8List? data = await getBytesFromAsset("assets/icons/map_marker.png", 100);
  return BitmapDescriptor.fromBytes(data!);
}

// then call the function to create a custom marker.
BitmapDescriptor? _marker = await createCustomMarkerBitmap();

final Marker marker = Marker(
        markerId: _markerId,
        position: _position,
        icon: _marker, // use the marker
        infoWindow: _infoWindow,
        onTap: () {},
      );
```

Comment: Use this website to generate different style for your default google map. https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com